Prediction of the drag coefficient at high Reynolds number
The picture reflects the classical variation of the drag coefficient of the sphere concerning Reynolds number.

For the Reynolds number chosen, we know that the drag coefficient is the summation of the frictional drag and the form (pressure) drag.  Can we predict the value of the drag coefficient at zone (4) at the limit of the subcritical regime, from drag coefficient values at zone (2) moderate Reynolds number regime? Does the idea violate our current understanding of the problem?

You can predict it using computational fluid dynamics as long as the flow remains laminar.  If the flow is turbulent, CFD is not as accurate.

Thanks so much for the answer. However, my question is more about theory and states that if we know the drag coefficient of a certain object let's say at Re = 50, can we predict the form drag of the same object at Re = 100000, for example?

In my judgment, no, not accurately.
